# Single entry point for displaying page and ajax calls

Tags: php, ajax

I have a single entry into my site: `http://mysite.com/index.php?this=that&andthis=that`.  I use it for all tasks such as originally displaying a page, submitting a form, and ajax calls.  I then route it to the appropriate task.

Are there any reason why it is preferred to have another entry into the the site for ajax calls such as `http://mysite.com/ajax.php` instead of index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know in my modest experience, there is no technical reason for separating the both behaviors.

But you might need to have some specific treatment, like when you have an ajax request you need to handle errors and display them to the user differently.

e.g: for exceptions, you may need to enclose your code in a try catch, and return the error message in a json format:

```
try{
    // your AJAX request code here
} catch (Exception $e){
    // threat error here
    $msgErr = $e->getMessage();

    echo json_encode( array( "success"=>"failure", "msg" => $msgErr ) );
}
```

and you show the message to the end user in an alert message box, so once you have such needs it more logic to make a separate entry point for ajax request in order to automate your behavior instead of making again every time.

I hope I've made my tought clear enough, if not I would be happy to try again.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Abu,  Your opinion matches mine.  I will wait a bit to see if anyone else chimes in.